# JPA - Reusing Specifications from different classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpa-criteria

Let's say I have 2 classes defined this way

```
class A{
    private String name;
}

class B{
    private A a;
    private String bla;
}
```

And also have predicates for A and B, like this

```
public static Specification<A> hasName(String name) {
        return (a, cq, cb) -> {
            return cb.and(a.get("name").in(name));
        };
    }
```

and

```
public static Specification<B> hasBla(String bla) {
        return (b, cq, cb) -> {
            return cb.and(b.get("bla").in(bla));
        };
    }
```

Having that both predicates are for different classes, is there a way to use both in the same query? for example, get elements that have the matching name and bla

Comment: How would that be possible/make any sense? As don't have a `bla` and Bs don't have a `name`?

Comment: Don't understand your comment, I have two criteria, one for each class checking its own parameters, then want to mix them in a single query, so with same code, I can query A's by name, B's by bla, or B's for name and bla on separate repo calls